# Normalization, i need to lessen my work as possible

Tags: sql

please help me with this little problem
this is my code. my problem is i have thousands of data and  i dont want to type all the data. what could be the best but easy program for this?
i use SQL, all data are coded is the same format

```
create table Subjects
(Subject_code nvarchar(10) primary key
,Subject_name nvarchar(20)
,Description nvarchar(MAX)
,Units int)

create table Schedules
(Schedule_ID int primary key identity(650500,1)
,Section nvarchar(10) 
,Subject_code nvarchar(10) foreign key references Subjects(Subject_code)
as 
select subject_code from subject 
where  subject_code = subject_code
,Days nvarchar(10)
,Time time
,Room nvarchar(10))
```

Comment: Is the problem that you have the data for your database's tables in a different format, and you need to convert it for insertion into your database? Or is it something else?

Comment: Best but easy program for what? You have some table definitions here, and a vague proclamation that you have some data, somewhere -- do you want to populate the tables? The best way to do this would depend on what form the data are in.

Comment: What format is your data in?

Answer (score 2):

Virtually all databases have an import utility - use that.

Typically, you create a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file of the data and have the database import it into your table(s).

You haven't specified *which* database you're using, so I can't be more specific than that.

Comment: i dont have problems about format because i made them all using SQL 
my main problems is what code or syntax should i used inorder to minimize the work

Answer (score 0):

In case you mean insert the data from table into another (without typing it) - which is what I understood you can do something like this, I hope this is what you meant:

```
 insert into Schedules ( col1, col2, col3 )
 select otherCol1, otherCol2, otherCol3
 from SomeSourceTable
```